# install4j Auto-Update, check connection

Tags: install4j

I have a problem with the auto-update function on install4j.

If I set the "launch mode" to "when first window is shown", the update window will popup behind the Swing GUI.

So i tried "Blocking at startup" which works fine if there is an Internet-connecion.
Problem is, if there is no connection, the blocking will take more than 20 seconds.
Is there a way to check a connection beforehand of set a timeout to a smaller amount of time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to call the updater in your own code to get more flexibility. Then you can check if there is an update and only launch the updater in that case.

To get a code snippet, go to Installer->Screens & Actions, select the updater and activate the the "Launcher integration" tab, then click on "Start integration wizard".

In the "Update check" section of the wizard, select "Yes, check of the update schedule requires an invocation".